# Why doesn't updating this model trigger validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, validation

With Rails 3.1, I have:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :participations

  validates :users, :presence => true
end
```

In my unit test, I do:

```
user = User.create(:name => "Bob")
status1 = Status.create(:description => "available")
user.statuses << status1
```

and get:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: users can't be blank

but, if instead of the last line I do:

```
status1.users << user
```

it works fine.

Why does the validation get triggered for:

```
user.statuses << status1
```

---

UPDATE:

the test in full

```
 test "Return all statuses associated with the manager" do
    manager = Manager.create(:email => "foo@bar.com", :password => "password", :password_confirmation => "password")

    workshop = Workshop.create(:name => "Bob Autos")
    manager.workshop = workshop
    manager.save

    user = User.create(:name => "a customer")

    workshop.users << user

    status1 = Status.create(:description => "Car is ready")
    status2 = Status.create(:description => "problem with exhaust")
    status3 = Status.create(:description => "parts delivered")

    user.statuses << status1
    user.statuses << status2

    assert_equal([status1, status2], manager.statuses)

    user.statuses << status3

    assert_equal([status1, status2, status3], manager.statuses)
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation is on `Status`, not on `User`. A model's validation is only triggered when that model is updated, and you didn't actually update the `User` model (since `statuses` is an association, not a field).

If you want validation on one object to trigger validation on another, you should use `validates_associated`:

```
class Status
  validates_associated :users
end
```

(On a related note, though, why does a Status have many users? Seems like a Status should only be on one user.)

Comment: Thanks john, that helps, but why does the validation "users can't be blank" even get triggered there? because I am in the process of assigning a user to the status. I guess i would have been less surprised if the validation error occurred when the status was actually being created. It's intentional :-) my app will allow shared statuses.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `status1.users` collection isn't automatically updated when you do `user.statuses << status1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so why does the collection not getting updated result in the validation getting triggered?

Comment: @pingu Why do you need the users validation on the Status model? It means that you can't save a status without having users already assigned (which is what Status.create is trying to do)